Network calls are not functioning when android app is in the background
we have developed an Android app. However, on some phones, after some time of installation, the app is working, but network calls are not functioning when it is in the background. The app works fine when we launch it and use any feature, but it does not work when it is in the background. Initially, the app works fine in the background for some days after installation, but after a few days, network calls stop working.
As network calls work in the background when we install the app, they should continue to work for as long as the app remains installed on the phone.

Any piece of code? Of your service? It's better to use WorkManager in such cases, both foreground and background services are killed by OS pretty quickly (approx. in 2-3 days)

@PineapplePie We are calling api through broadcast receiver, so how we can use work manager?

It's even more crucial then to move to WorkManager... Broadcast receivers have time limitations - if your API is slow and hanging, you might not get any result from the request, it will be cut off by the system. I'm not sure though about your question, what's the problem of starting jobs? You can enqueue a job from broadcast receivers without any problems. Even basically from any place in the app :)
